# WeakHashMap doesn't remove obsolete entries

Tags: java

How can I model the removal of entries in WeakHashMap if there are no active references to one of it keys. I have next code:

```
WeakHashMap<Integer, String> weakMap = new WeakHashMap<Integer, String>();
Integer st1 = 5;
Integer st2 = 6;
String val = "BB";
weakMap.put(st1, "AA");
weakMap.put(st2, val);
st1 = 10;
//st1 = null;
//System.gc();
for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
   System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "  " + entry.getValue());
}
```

The output is always

```
6  BB
5  AA
```

But I expect to get only `6  BB`
Even if I decomment commented lines it still produce the same output. As I understand if the key in `WeakHashMap` has no active reference somewhere else outside this `weakHashMap` the entry with the specified key has to be removed. Am I right? If no, please, suggest the right solution.

Comment: System.gc doesnt doesnt guaranteed to do gc when you call.

Comment: Have changed that code as ColinD said and it works(with `System.gc()`) in every attempt that I have made, is it mean that I am simply lucky and gc performed in every attempt?

Comment: @maks: It may reliably do it in some JVMs but not others, or it may depend on some flags (I don't specifically). It's not required to, though, so it's not something you should rely on.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your keys are never garbage collected because `Integer`s from -128 to 127 are cached (assuming `Integer.valueOf` is used, which it is for autoboxed `int`s). You could use values outside that range or use `Integer st1 = new Integer(5)` to ensure you aren't using cached objects.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried with numbers out of that range and it works(mean removes). And what about Strings. I have tested it before this with String keys and it hasn't been removed too?

Comment: @maks: You were probably using `String` literals (e.g. `String key = "key";`). Those are interned as well.

Comment: When you say 'cashed' you mean that they are not stored in heap?

Comment: @maks: The `Integer` cache is stored in the heap, but it's static so it isn't GCed. `String` constants are interned in the permanent generation.

Comment: This could be one of the rare cases where a `new Integer(n)` is better than `Integer.valueOf(n)`. If you created a new `Integer` object per entry, you could be sure that the keys aren't in the `Integer`'s cache, and you could therefore use them in the `WeakHashMap`.

Answer (score 1):

The Integer objects from -1000 to 1000 (or somewhere thereabouts) are interned. This means that autoboxing and `valueOf()` return an object which is stored internally in `Integer` and hence never garbage collected. You will see the intended behavior if you do this:

```
Integer st1 = new Integer(5);
Integer st2 = new Integer(6);

...

st1 = 10;

System.gc();

...
```